# Transfering iPhone4 pics to iPad2?

Tags: iphone, data-transfer, photos

there
I know there's many ways to transfer multiple pictures from an iPhone to an iPad,but i want to transfer them using only the iPhone and iPad, without a PC or Mac. I was wondering if there was an app that would allow me to do this on the go.
Hope you nice guys can help me,ths!

Answer (score 4):

It is called iCloud and is released next Month.

Answer (score 3):

The [Apple iPad Camera Connection Kit](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MC531ZM/A?mco=MTY3ODQ5OTY) allows you to transfer pictures from a camera (including an iPhone) to an iPad via USB.

Comment: If you are willing to spend the money ($30 I think) on the kit and it's convenient to carry the small adapter that comes in the "kit", then this is truly the best way to get pics/movies from iPhone to iPad. It's drop dead simple (really) and faster than any wireless solution.

Answer (score 2):

you can use [Dropbox](http://www.dropbox.com) to share files between your devices

Answer (score 0):

[This article](http://createrenewrestore.wordpress.com/2011/08/19/ios-device-bluetooth-transfer/) suggests that LY MobileSoft  has developed an app that allows pictures to be shared between iOS devices.

Answer (score 0):

Upload all of the pictures from the iPhone to a photo sharing service (ie. Flickr, Photobucket, Google, et al.), and then download them using the same app on the iPad.  It might be tedious, but it's possible now (instead of waiting for iCloud)

Answer (score 0):

You may use [PhotoSync](http://itunes.apple.com/ch/app/photosync-drahtlos-fotos-und/id415850124?mt=8) to transfer pictures between iPhone/iPad/Mac/PC by Wi-Fi.